# mod_rewrite redirect all unmatched rules to a common file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have all my rewrite rules setup and working in .htaccess but I need to redirect all unmatched rules to a common place.

Here are the rules:

```
# add trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} -d
RewriteRule ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ [R]

# redirect directories to old site if it exists    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/old_site/$0 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) old_site/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

#redirect files to old site if they exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/old_site/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) old_site/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This works great, but trying to redirect the rest of the traffic (all unmatched rules) to index.php just over writes all the rules above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

How can I insure this part only gets executed if nothing else (I guess except the trailing slash part) was matched?

EDIT:
As per @Jon Lin I've changed the last three lines to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Which now works for everything but directories that don't end in a slash. I can't put [L] on the first rule because I need it to re-write further to a different directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rule is never going to get applied because the %{REQUEST_FILENAME} is never going to be a directory *and* not a directory at the same time. If you want existing directories and files to not get rewritten (like if you link to an image), then include these conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

The rule you have is fine. But you may want to include a `[L]` at the end of it.

Also, the first rule you have, you are checking if the document root is a directory (it should), that means that rule will always be applied, which means `/index.php` is going to get rewritten to `/index.php/`. I think you may be looking for %{REQUEST_FILENAME} instead of %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}.

Comment: Thanks I've added the rules but it doesn't work for directories that don't end in a slash, the first rule adds a slash to things that don't have a dot and a slash, so it won't rewrite index.php to index.php/ I've changed to REQUEST_FILENAME but it makes no difference.

Comment: You were right after all because I was Redirecting, I needed the L at the end of that now it's working perfect!